# Looking for a lightweight NTLM HTTP proxy server

Tags: ntlm, http-proxy

For some testing, I am looking for an NTLM HTTP proxy server. The server should authenticate the clients, not delegate that authentication to an upstream "real" NTLM proxy server (like "[NTLMAPS](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)" or "[CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)" does).

What is the easiest way to create an HTTP proxy server that requires NTLM authentication?

I would like to be able to add users to this proxy and control their passwords. If creating a Windows Domain is the only way to achieve that, then please include the easiest way to get to that point in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stumbling upon your question. We too had to test against a NTLMv2 capable http proxy (from Java).

In the end, we used a product called [WinGate](https://www.wingate.com), which is free up to some users. We just installed that on a Windows Machine in a VM.
The users can be just created directly in WinGate (no AD needed).

Also see howto enable NTLMv2: http://help.qbik.com/index.php?topic_id=389

Note: I am *not* affilitated with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Httpd server and configure it to use NTLM authentication.
See my attempt here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48238953/9043528

You can add users by creating them on the windows machine you are running the server.